# How do I replace href in a button with onClick?

Tags: react-typescript

I am new to Typescript, but I have a button that I want to add an onClick to. Right now there is a href tag in the button, and I want to remove the href and replace it with an onClick that will perform the action

```js
<PrimaryButton
    className={}
    href={}
    target={}
          >
            {/* some code */}
</PrimaryButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an `onClick` prop do this

```
function PrimaryButton({ onButtonClick }) {
  return ( 
    <button onClick={onButtonClick}>
      // button content
    </button>
  )
}

export default PrimaryButton
```

When you use the component just pass a function / or state modifier as a value of your `onButtonClick` prop.

```
import PrimaryButton from './components/Buttons/PrimaryButton'

function Home() {

  function handlePrimaryButtonClick() {
    // Do whatever you want to do on PrimaryButton click
  }

  return (
    <PrimaryButton onButtonClick={() => handlePrimaryButtonClick()}
  )
}
```